# How to generate war file and deploy to tomcat server using jenkins

Tags: eclipse, svn, jenkins, ant, jenkins-plugins

I have developed a sample login web application in Eclipse IDE and the same project I have uploaded to SVN. After that I am configuring the jenkins and integrated with SVN. Now I want to generate a war file using jenkins and trying to deploy to the tomcat server. In the project I used ANT building tool and I generated build.xml
Now my question is how to configure with tomact server and how I can generate war file and deploy to the server. I am not understanding how to invoke ANT and what to give path in WAR/EAR files(already i downloaded deploy plugin) and context path in post-build actions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the first thing you should do is to focus on building the WAR file using ANT (You can check this tutorial if you want - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ant/ant_creating_war_files.htm). After that, you can go to Jenkins, where you could set up in different ways. You may have a task to generate the WAR and another task triggered after this one that simply copy the file to the Tomcat folder.

Comment: Thank you Dan-Dev.. for your valuable suggestion